# Instagram like scroll header

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

im trying to make a app that behaves similar to instagram. I have a listview and a header menu on top of the listview. When the user scrolls the listview the header menu should scroll out of view just like the blue header in instagram and come back down when the user scrolls up. Im not sure how to do this. Any help

Answer (score 1):

I've never used instagram but you could be looking for something like https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView or https://github.com/eowise/recyclerview-stickyheaders